# Реализация Drag&Drop на своем виджете

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-n-drop, qlistwidget, qtreeview

У меня есть виджет и я хочу сделать какие-нибудь действия с файлами, после перетаскивания файлов на мой виджет.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, \
    QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag & Drop')

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Drag and drop the file:'))
        main_layout.addStretch()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(500, 350)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget,
                             QVBoxLayout, QListWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QDir


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Drag & Drop')
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 500, 400)

        # Даем разрешение на Drop
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.list_files = QListWidget()
        self.label_total_files = QLabel()

        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        model.setReadOnly(False)

        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))
        self.tree.setSelectionMode(QTreeView.SingleSelection)
        self.tree.setDragDropMode(QTreeView.InternalMove)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Перетащите файл:'))
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_files)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_total_files)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self._update_states()

    def _update_states(self):
        self.label_total_files.setText('Files: {}'.format(self.list_files.count()))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        # Тут выполняются проверки и дается (или нет) разрешение на Drop

        mime = event.mimeData()

        # Если перемещаются ссылки
        if mime.hasUrls():
            # Разрешаем
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # Обработка события Drop

        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            file_name = url.toLocalFile()
            self.list_files.addItem(file_name)

        self._update_states()

        return super().dropEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выглядит очень круто :)

Comment: Пока разбирал ваш код, понял что класс Tree не нужен, поэтому предлагаю его убрать -- будет тоже самое, но без кучи кода. Да и при некоторых событиях код упадет -- отсутствуют QFileInfo и QFile

Comment: Совет: лучше не использовать `self.setGeometry(500, 100, 500, 400)` в конструкторе -- размер виджета и ,особенно, его положение на экране Qt сам рассчитывает и лучше стандартное поведение

Answer (score 3):

Минимальная реализация `Drag & Drop` потребует следующих шагов:

- Вызов метода [setAcceptDrops](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop) и передача ему `True` разрешает виджету обрабатывать события Drop.
- Переопределение метода-события [dragEnterEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) позволит принимать объекты Drag и, при нужде, фильтровать их по какому-либо признаку.
- Переопределение метода-события [dropEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dropEvent) позволит обработать сброшенные объекты.

---

[В этом примере](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8101f6a3fe3e58775cc413fcb539c70bca539c85/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5_drag_and_drop.py) виджет будет принимать на себя папки и файлы, и добавлять их в свой список.

Код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QListWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Drag & Drop')

        # Даем разрешение на Drop
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.list_files = QListWidget()
        self.label_total_files = QLabel()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Drag and drop the file:'))
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_files)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_total_files)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self._update_states()

    def _update_states(self):
        self.label_total_files.setText('Files: {}'.format(self.list_files.count()))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        # Тут выполняются проверки и дается (или нет) разрешение на Drop

        mime = event.mimeData()

        # Если перемещаются ссылки
        if mime.hasUrls():
            # Разрешаем
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # Обработка события Drop

        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            file_name = url.toLocalFile()
            self.list_files.addItem(file_name)

        self._update_states()

        return super().dropEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(500, 350)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Если интересно, [тут есть пример `Drag & Drop`](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/c54c433f13330503c42381319c153fbfede63670/get_md5_file), в котором обрабатывается строго 1 файл и после сброса на окно виджета подсчитывается его md5-хеш.